# Android - Use retrofit2 to request dynamic IP address

Tags: android, retrofit2, cleartext

Using Retrofit2 to perform network requests, and now trying to call a service which is in a configurable IP dress, but I get `CLEARTEXT communication to **IP_ADDRESS*** not permitted by network security policy`.

I have read in forums that we can add the IP address to `network_security_config.xml`, but I need address to be dynamically. Also tried to add in manifest the flag `usesCleartextTraffic` but same error raises (tested on Android 10)

How can I request a dynamic IP address without having to specify it in `network_security_config.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below xml code for network_security_config.xml

```
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

its should work!
im sorry for my weak english